# Yii2 renderPartial detailview in other view

Tags: yii2

I have a problem with renderPartial a detailview(farmacia/view) in a view(farmacia/receta), I don have idea to do that, the code below is a test can fix it

FarmaciaController:

[image]

Farmacia view:

[image]

Farmacia receta:

[image]

Please help me with a example or a tutorial to guide me

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If they're helpful, here's some general guidelines on how to ask questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. One suggestion I might propose would be to explain your error as part of the question itself (rather than providing links to images).

Comment: don't post image ... post text code ..

Answer (score -1):

On a first glance at images of your code I see that you have not passed variable `$receta`
to a receta view. Then you are trying to send it (`$receta`) to the view ‘`view`’. Furthermore you are using `$receta` in your ‘`view`’ view but variable name is `$model` (you passed `$receta` as ‘model’). Also in a view ‘`view`’ you have `$this` which is an object of View class so when you use

> $this->render(‘view’)

it is by design a [partial view](https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/reusing-views-via-partials/) and additionaly it doesn’t call `actionView` in controller, test it by echoing and stoping execution in action.